# How many different two way partition exists on a $2$-sphere using great circle for $n$ points?

Tags: spheres, set-partition

Suppose there are $n$ unique points on a $2$-sphere with no three points co-great circle. And we can choose a great circle passing through one of the points that partition the rest points into two subsets. If any point passes the great circle is excluded from the final partition.

How many ways can there be for all possible partitions?

Comment: Choose your point to be the north pole and your great circle to be GMT & the other half. Now rotate this through $180$ to get $n-1$ different partitions. Repeat this for the $n$ points ... so $n(n-1)$ possible partitions in toto.

Comment: would choosing a different point to form a great circle generates different partitions?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I have edited my previous comment ... & read the question.

Comment: Is it allowed by the question that we can choose a great circle that passes through two points, thereby partitioning the remaining $n -2$ points into two subsets?

Comment: yes, so it would be a mixture of partition of  $n-1$ and $n-2$ points

Answer (score 0):

For each point there are $n-1$ partitions with $n-1$ points and $n-1$ partitions with $n-2$ points.  Summing over all points will count partitions with $n-2$ points twice.  So there are $$n(n-1)+n(n-1)/2 = \tfrac32n(n-1)$$ in total.